# How do I play an .swf file frame-by-frame on a Mac?

Tags: mac, swf, adobe-flash

How do I play an .swf file frame-by-frame on a Mac?

On Windows I can do this using a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> combination.

Answer (score 0):

[SWF & FLV Player](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/video/swfflvplayer.html)

From the site:

> SWF & FLV Player by Eltima Software offers advanced and unique features that allow you to play, rewind, fast-forward and preview SWF and FLV files **frame-by-frame**

Answer (score 0):

You can also open some SWFs and FLVs in Quicktime, just hit the right or left arrows. You may need Perian. It depends a lot on how the Flash was compiled and what is happening in the scene.